Default Usermeta Entries for every newly created user?
we have a Buddyboss page running with 30k users. Our usermeta Table is growing fast because of a few plugins we use which all seem to write a lot of settings to it. I try to remove as many obsolete or unneeded Usermeta Entries as possible.
hence my question is: For every newly added user there seem to be a few default WP-based Usermeta entries, this is the meta_key list:

nickname
syntax_highlighting
use_ssl
admin_color
rich_editing
show_admin_bar_front
locale

A Buddyboss/Buddypress user usually never accesses WP-Admin as such - so I guess most of these are irrelevant, isn't it? And even if not, all values are anyhow the same! What do you think?? These alone are already 7*30k = 210k entries (growing the table as well the index by a lot).
Is there any harm removing those? I hope at worst they get re-created...
Thanks!

I believe it will not create any issue because these are mainly used if the user is accessing the WP Admin but we should done this proper plan by taking the backup of database first and then remove these fields and then testing the website to verify everything working fine or not and if anything goes wrong then just restore the backup.

Maybe I will do one thing: I will just rename those meta_keys. This way, they are kept in the database and can quickly be recovered by renaming back. If everything still works as expected, I will finally remove them from the DB

That also looks like the good idea, we can got with this.
